# how to prevent the insertion of extra quotes in the JSONOBject value?

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
public JSONArray updatedGames() {
    JSONArray ar = new JSONArray();

    try {
        conn = connection.getConnection();
        String query = "CALL websocket_games(2)";
        CallableStatement custStmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
        rs = custStmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("id "+rs.getString("our_game_id"));
            JsonProvider provider = JsonProvider.provider();
            JsonObject updatemessage = provider.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("game_id", rs.getString("our_game_id"))
                    .add("date", rs.getString("dat"))
                    .build();
            ar.put(updatemessage);
        }
        if(ar.length()>0){
            System.out.println("provider "+ar.getString(0) );
        }


        rs.close();
        custStmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("number of games " + ar.length());
    return ar;
}
```

the output for the above function is `{"game_id":"\"8240\"","date":"\"2015-08-18\""}`
however my desired output is `{"game_id":"8240","date":"2015-08-18"}`.

how can i prevent the insertion of those extra quotes in the JSONOBject value?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you're questions is not of very good quality. I think you might need to refactor your question a bit. See this article about good question guidelines. http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: are the extra quotes already on the string that you get back from rs.getString("our_game_id")

Comment: no they are not i sysd-out independently and they dont have quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //------please try this instead of your while loop ----------
   JSONArray ar = new JSONArray();
   while (rs.next()){
         System.out.println("id "+rs.getString("our_game_id"));
         JsonObject updatemessage = new JsonObject();
         updatemessage.put("game_id", rs.getString("our_game_id"));
         updatemessage.put("date"   , rs.getString("dat"));
         ar.add(updatemessage);
   }

   if(ar.length()>0){
          System.out.println("provider "+ar.getString(0) );
   }
```

note : please check your database fields values...

Comment: thanks it worked like a charm. turns out that JsonProvider was the issue i decided to use JSONObject class in org.json.JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

**Your issue is not in your Java code.**

Either your database contains those fields with already quoted values or your `websocket_games` stored procedure adds those quotes.